# Swapping two DB rows without violating constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, atomic

I have a table `regionkey`:

```
areaid  -- primary key, int
region  -- char(4)
locale  -- char(4)
```

The entire rest of the database is foreign-keyed to areaid.  In this table there is an index on (region, locale) with a unique constraint.

The problem is that I have two records:

```
101   MICH   DETR
102   ILLI   CHIC
```

And I need to swap the (region,locale) fields between them, so that I wind up with:

```
101   ILLI   CHIC
102   MICH   DETR
```

The naive approach won't work because it violates the unique index on region and locale:

```
update regionkey
     set region='ILLI', locale='CHIC' where areaid = 101; -- FAILS
update regionkey
     set region='MICH', locale='DETR' where areaid = 102;
```

How can I do this?  Is there an atomic way to make the swap?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't defer constraint checks in SQL Server over multiple statements (unless you DISABLE) so you have to avoid the conflict or do it in one statement

```
update
    regionkey 
set
    region= CASE areaid WHEN 101 THEN 'ILLI' ELSE 'MICH' END, 
    locale= CASE areaid WHEN 101 THEN 'CHIC' ELSE 'DETR' END
where
    areaid IN (101, 102);
```

or, more conventionally (in a transaction this one)

```
update regionkey 
     set region='AAAA', locale='BBBB' where areaid = 101;
update regionkey 
     set region='MICH', locale='DETR' where areaid = 102;
update regionkey 
     set region='ILLI', locale='CHIC' where areaid = 101;
```

Edit: Why not swap keys not values? It usually achieves the sane result unless areaid has some meaning

```
update
    regionkey 
set
    areaid = 203 - areaid 
where
    areaid IN (101, 102);
```

Comment: This may just be crazy enough to work. Do you think he should wrap it in a transaction?

Comment: a single insert is a single implicit transaction anyway

Comment: Just a bit quicker than I, @gbn ;-)

Comment: The first gives a syntax error near the first comma.  I considered the second option, but since there might be multiple occurances of this going on at the same time I can't rely on "AAAA" and "BBBB" being unique without a boatload of hackery.

Comment: The first solution (with the "END") works great.  You beat me to the edit by seconds.

Comment: @gbn: There's a lot more going on in these records than I let on.   Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

BEst bet is to make three updates. Update the first record to a temp set of values, update the second record and then reupdate the first record to the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simple act of wrapping it in a transaction?

I understand you can set up constraints to allow it to only enforce the constraint at the end of a transaction but I am unsure if your constraints are set up that way.

Comment: There is no "defer constraint" in SQL Server, unless you explicitly use DISABLE which is a DDL statement

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, which may not be the safest for large record sets, would be to set **both** records to '    ' for both region & locale, and then execute two update statements, one for each record, like so:

```
UPDATE
    regionkey
SET
   region = '    ',
   locale = '    '
WHERE
    areaid in (101,102)

UPDATE
    regionkey
SET
    region = 'ILLI',
    locale = 'CHIC'
WHERE
    areaid = 101

UPDATE
    regionkey
SET
    region = 'MICH',
    locale = 'DETR'
WHERE
    areaid = 102
```

Like I said, this is probably not the safest way to go, but for a small data set it should be OK.

UPDATE: Larry correctly pointed out that the first UPDATE statement will violate the UNIQUE constraint. Use this instead for the first UPDATE:

```
UPDATE
    regionkey
SET
    region = areaid,
    locale = areaid
WHERE
    areaid in (101,102)
```

This way each intermediate region and locale is (or should be) unique.

Comment: Same problem — the initial UPDATE will violate UNIQUEness on region, locale.